# SQL SELECT from multiple tables + IN LIST

Tags: mysql, sql, select

How can I get every article + name of all authors in the article (different from article to another)

```
Users table :
ID NAME FNAME
1  A    AA
2  B    BB
3  C    CC
4  D    DD

Articles
ID AUTHOR title
1  1,3    ty
2  4      tz

Results
A.id A.title USER1_name USER2_name
1    ty      A          C
2    tz      D          no user
```

Its working thanks, is there a way to make the one user column instead of two like this :

```
ID  TITLE NAME
1   ty    A,C
2   yy    B,C,E
```

because sometimes we have mote than 7 authors :/

Comment: maximum of 2 authors per article?

Comment: The first step would be changing your table structure. Never, never, never store multiple values in one column!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming maximum of 2 authors per article

```
select a.id, a.title, b.u1, b.u2
from articles a
join (
  select if(a.id=b.id,a.id,concat(a.id,',',b.id)) author, a.name u1, if(a.id=b.id,'no user',b.name) u2
  from users a
  join users b) b on a.author = b.author;
```

[demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/87c99/4)

Comment: Its working thanks, is there a way to make the one user column instead of two like above.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this

```
SELECT A.id, A.title, A.name
FROM USERS U, ARTICLES A
WHERE U.id in (A.author)
```

Answer (score 0):

use `concat()` of mysql to combine user names in one column.

Comment: While this may be correct, it would be helpful if you could provide a simple example.